# Showing notification window in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

in my app, i have a notification popup window that shows the latest messages, my example does not show opening, but that isnt the main of the conversation, the problem is that wwhen i resize the window, by button link with the bell notification on the right disapears, when it should be showing always, even in mobile.
The toggle menu appears has should it be, but in mobile view the bell link menu notifcation should appear at his side.

Whats wrong with my html code? Im using bootstrap

Ex:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmxQwO?editors=1010

Html:

```
 <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown ng-isolate-scope">
    <a id="dLabel" role="button" class="icon-wrapper" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-click="notificationCtrl.updateDateTime()" data-target="#">
        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"><span class="badge-notification ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="notificationCtrl.nrNotifications > 0"> 0</span></i>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu notifications" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">

        <li class="dropdown-header">
            Notificações
        </li>


        <div class="notifications-wrapper">
            <!-- ngRepeat: notification in notificationCtrl.notifications | limitTo: 5 --><a ng-repeat="notification in notificationCtrl.notifications | limitTo: 5 " class="content ng-scope" href="">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 notification-grid item-title notification-item">


                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 notification-grid">
                        <!-- USER -->
                        <strong class="ng-binding"></strong>

                        <!-- ngIf: notification.operation == 'first_register' -->



                        <!-- NOTIFICAÇÔES -->


                        <div>
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"><span class="item-info ng-binding"> há 2 meses atrás</span></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a><!-- end ngRepeat: notification in notificationCtrl.notifications | limitTo: 5 --><a ng-repeat="notification in notificationCtrl.notifications | limitTo: 5 " class="content ng-scope" href="">

                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 notification-grid item-title notification-item">



                    <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 notification-grid">
                        <!-- USER -->

                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"><span class="item-info ng-binding"> há 2 meses atrás</span></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>

        </div>


    </ul>

</li>
                    </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: data-toggle is collapse which contains the notification. If you always want to show then keep it out of div having class collapse.

Comment: i tried already but it goes always the right of the toggle, and this is because is not inside same div, but i need this and the left of the toggle